# Mysql / php - id numbers reached 9999 and started counting from 0001

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, auto-increment

I have a PHP website which takes customer applications. Each application is given an ID number which is incremental.

Recently the site reached application id number 9999 but instead of continuing on to 10000 it reverted back to 0001

Any ideas why this happened - perhaps some kind of php or mysql setting, range or limit?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the data type of the column?

Comment: and length of data type?

Comment: post the results of the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourApplicationTable` and you'll likely see as others have suggested that the primary key column is too small or something like that. How are your applications stored? We're assuming in a database.

Comment: Actually I'm curious why it doesn't just error out. In my experience when an primary key auto increment column is too small it just dies when you try to insert another record beyond its limit

Comment: Perhaps , somewhere you reset the autoincrement. like `ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there was some forming applied in the php to limit to 4 digits (0000) so when it reached 10000 it was cutting off the first 1. This was causing it to appear as 0001 etc in the backend and other places...

As a consequence it was also sending out the cut version of the id nmber in emails to applicants and causing all sorts of mess lol!

Took a while to find the right file because the original coder is not available!

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

it is likely the size of the `int` allowed for the incrementing primary key.

Comment: In phpmyadmin i see...

field= idnumber type=int(11) null=No default =None auto_increment

Comment: all I can assume then is it is something in the code causing your issue.

Comment: ok strange thing we have found out is that in thew database it appears the next id number would be 10047 so it is actually going beyond 9999 - but for some reason in the front end its showing as 0001

Comment: yes there was some forming applied in the php to limit to 4 digits (0000) so when it reached 10000 it was cutting off the first 1. Took a while to find the right file because the original coder is not available! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

please do this in table structure for id `int(11)`
in length give 11